# QTableView change row color based on a value

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

I have a `QTableView` that I implemented with my own model subclassed from `QAbstractTableModel`.  I want to be able to change the row color to red when one of the fields in the row has a certain value.  I saw a lot of examples where the answer is to call the models `setData` and use `Qt::BackgroundRole` to change the background color.  Since I subclassed the `AbstractTableModel` I reimplemented `setData` and `data` so calling models `setData` does nothing with the background color role since I'm only handling data whose role is `Qt::DisplayRole`.

I guess my first question is : Is there an easier way to change the color of the entire role?  If not, I'm guessing I have to implement that part in `setData` and `data` to handle the `BackgroundRole` which I have no idea how to do so if anyone has examples on how to do this it would really help a lot...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That was easier than i thought...  In my data method i added a check for

```
if (role == Qt::BackgroundColorRole)
```

In that if block. i check do the value comparison to see if thats the row i have to change the color for and if it is i return:

```
return QVariant(QColor(Qt::red));
```

Answer (score 4):

A better answer is to use a `delegate` provided by the `view` for this task and not to touch the `model` at all.  Why should the model know anything about what color you want the view to be? What happens if you want multiple views to behave differently? ETC.

You can use `setColumnDelegate`, or `setRowDelegate` or a number of other mechanisms. Take a look at those functions for complete answer.

Comment: (absolutely true) uv for suggesting the proper thing! it's common to see workarounds that end-up creating lots of technical debt.